# Using upfront knowledge of connected features in policy or value approximation RL

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am using reinforcement learning to develop a generative design tool that is used to design mechanical linkages. Given the continuous nature of the states I am working with, I am experimenting with function approximations. Currently, I am using linear function approximation to approximate the Q function, using SARSA to optimize the weights throughout multiple epochs.

The state consists of the current linkage design, described by a matrix holding the coordinates of all hinges, and an adjacency matrix, describing in binary numbers which hinges are connected. Actions consist of adding/removing hinge-points and links. The resulting mechanism is kinematically simulated and its trajectory scored against a given goal (at this point: drawing a straight line).

My question: I can easily make features about hinge locations and features about link lenghts, but only when combined with topology information is this really valuable. How can I 'show' my actor that certain features are 'connected'?

It seems inefficient to have the actor figure these relations out by itself when they are readily available.